# FastAPI: Performance results differ between run_in_threadpool() and run_in_executor() with ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi, starlette, apachebench

Here's a minimal reproducible example of my FastAPI app. I have a strange behavior and I'm not sure I understand the reason.

I'm using ApacheBench (`ab`) to send multiple requests as follows:

```
ab -n 1000 -c 50 -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'x-data-origin: source' 'http://localhost:8001/test/async'
```

**FastAPI app**

```
import time
import asyncio
import enum
from typing import Any

from fastapi import FastAPI, Path, Body
from starlette.concurrency import run_in_threadpool

app = FastAPI()
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
def sync_func() -> None:
    time.sleep(3)
    print("sync func")

async def sync_async_with_fastapi_thread() -> None:
    await run_in_threadpool( time.sleep, 3)
    print("sync async with fastapi thread")

async def sync_async_func() -> None:
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, time.sleep, 3)

async def async_func() -> Any:
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("async func")

@app.get("/test/sync")
def test_sync() -> None:
    sync_func()
    print("sync")

@app.get("/test/async")
async def test_async() -> None:
    await async_func()
    print("async")

@app.get("/test/sync_async")
async def test_sync_async() -> None:
    await sync_async_func()
    print("sync async")

@app.get("/test/sync_async_fastapi")
async def test_sync_async_with_fastapi_thread() -> None:
    await sync_async_with_fastapi_thread()
    print("sync async with fastapi thread")
```

Here's the ApacheBench results:

**async with (asyncio.sleep)** :
*Concurrency Level:      50

- Time taken for tests:   63.528 seconds
- Complete requests:      1000
- Failed requests:        0
- Total transferred:      128000 bytes
- HTML transferred:       4000 bytes
- Requests per second:    15.74 [#/sec] (mean)
- **Time per request:       3176.407 [ms] (mean)**
- Time per request:       63.528 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
  Transfer rate:          1.97 [Kbytes/sec] received*

**sync (with time.sleep):**
Concurrency Level:      50

- *Time taken for tests:   78.615 seconds
- Complete requests:      1000
- Failed requests:        0
- Total transferred:      128000 bytes
- HTML transferred:       4000 bytes
- Requests per second:    12.72 [#/sec] (mean)
- **Time per request:       3930.751 [ms] (mean)**
- Time per request:       78.615 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
  Transfer rate:          1.59 [Kbytes/sec] received*

**sync_async (time sleep with run_in_executor) :** *Concurrency Level:      50

- Time taken for tests:   256.201 seconds
- Complete requests:      1000
- Failed requests:        0
- Total transferred:      128000 bytes
- HTML transferred:       4000 bytes
- Requests per second:    3.90 [#/sec] (mean)
- **Time per request:       12810.038 [ms] (mean)**
- Time per request:       256.201 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
  Transfer rate:          0.49 [Kbytes/sec] received*

**sync_async_fastapi (time sleep with run_in threadpool):**
*Concurrency Level:      50

- Time taken for tests:   78.877 seconds
- Complete requests:      1000
- Failed requests:        0
- Total transferred:      128000 bytes
- HTML transferred:       4000 bytes
- Requests per second:    12.68 [#/sec] (mean)
- **Time per request:       3943.841 [ms] (mean)**
- Time per request:       78.877 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
  Transfer rate:          1.58 [Kbytes/sec] received*

In conclusion, I'm experiencing a surprising disparity in results, especially when using run_in_executor, where I'm encountering significantly higher average times (12 seconds). I don't understand this outcome.

--- EDIT ---
**After AKX answer.**

```
Here the code working as expected: 
import time
import asyncio
from anyio import to_thread

to_thread.current_default_thread_limiter().total_tokens = 200
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100)
def sync_func() -> None:
    time.sleep(3)
    print("sync func")

async def sync_async_with_fastapi_thread() -> None:
    await run_in_threadpool( time.sleep, 3)
    print("sync async with fastapi thread")

async def sync_async_func() -> None:
    await loop.run_in_executor(executor, time.sleep, 3)

async def async_func() -> Any:
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("async func")

@app.get("/test/sync")
def test_sync() -> None:
    sync_func()
    print("sync")

@app.get("/test/async")
async def test_async() -> None:
    await async_func()
    print("async")

@app.get("/test/sync_async")
async def test_sync_async() -> None:
    await sync_async_func()
    print("sync async")

@app.get("/test/sync_async_fastapi")
async def test_sync_async_with_fastapi_thread() -> None:
    await sync_async_with_fastapi_thread()
    print("sync async with fastapi thread")
```

Comment: Wow, great! Have you found anything other than the number of workers or the concurrency limit?

Comment: @Chris I indeed might have accepted the answer too quickly. But i can still undo. However, increasing the number of workers as suggested did resolve the issue on the sync_async route, and I went from an average of 12 seconds to about 3, similar to the async route. That was indeed the crux of the problem.

Comment: @Chris But you're correct, and it's a question I raised in their response. How does FastAPI handle the setup of the async part, because if I print anyio.to_thread.current_default_thread_limiter().total_tokens without the modification, I do get 40, and the performance of the async route is the best. However, it's inaccurate to say that /test/sync and /test/async yield the same result. There's a difference of just under 800 ms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Using [`run_in_threadpool()`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/ec417f7f84f3533f928a4bc2b8dd0c6c51cdbbad/starlette/concurrency.py#L36)

FastAPI is fully compatible with (and based on) [Starlette](https://www.starlette.io/), and hence, [with FastAPI you get all of Starlette's features](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/features/?h=starlette#starlette-features), such as the [`run_in_threadpool()`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/ec417f7f84f3533f928a4bc2b8dd0c6c51cdbbad/starlette/concurrency.py#L36) method. Starlette's `run_in_threadpool()`, which uses [`anyio.to_thread.run_sync()`](https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#anyio.to_thread.run_sync) behind the scenes, "will run the *sync* blocking function in a separate thread to ensure that the main thread (where coroutines are run) does not get blocked"—see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) and AnyIO's [Working with threads](https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/threads.html#working-with-threads) documentation for more details. Calling `run_in_threadpool()`—which internally calls `anyio.to_thread.run_sync()`, and subsequently, [`AsyncIOBackend.run_sync_in_worker_thread()`](https://github.com/agronholm/anyio/blob/137de708f40262e959d9d43178dda600432da56b/src/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py#L2088)—will return a coroutine that will then be `await`ed to get the eventual result of the *sync* function (e.g., `result = await run_in_threadpool(...)`), and hence, FastAPI will still work *asynchronously* (instead of calling that *synchronous* function directly, which would block the event loop that runs in the main thread, and hence, the main thread would get blocked as well). As can be seen in Starlette's source code (link is given above), the `run_in_threadpool()` function simply looks like this (supporting both *sequence* and *keyword* arguments):

```py
async def run_in_threadpool(
    func: typing.Callable[P, T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs
) -> T:
    if kwargs:  # pragma: no cover
        # run_sync doesn't accept 'kwargs', so bind them in here
        func = functools.partial(func, **kwargs)
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
```

As described in [AnyIO's documentation](https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/threads.html#adjusting-the-default-maximum-worker-thread-count):

> ##### Adjusting the default maximum worker thread count
>
> The **default** AnyIO worker thread limiter has a value of `40`, meaning
> that any calls to `to_thread.run_sync()` without an explicit `limiter`
> argument will cause a **maximum of `40` threads** to be spawned. You can
> adjust this limit like this:
>
> ```
> from anyio import to_thread
>
> async def foo():
>     # Set the maximum number of worker threads to 60
>     to_thread.current_default_thread_limiter().total_tokens = 60
> ```
>
> **Note**
>
> AnyIO’s default thread pool limiter does not affect the default thread pool executor on `asyncio`.

Since [FastAPI uses Startlette's `concurrency` module](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/3f3ee240dd8656962e94e89eceb3838508982068/fastapi/concurrency.py#L7) to run blocking functions in an external threadpool (the **same** threadpool is also used by FastAPI to run endpoints defined with normal `def` instead of `async def`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804)), the default value of the thread limiter, as shown above, is applied here as well, i.e., `40` threads maximum—see the relevant [`AsyncIOBackend.current_default_thread_limiter()`](https://github.com/agronholm/anyio/blob/137de708f40262e959d9d43178dda600432da56b/src/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py#L2435) method that returns the [`CapacityLimiter`](https://github.com/agronholm/anyio/blob/137de708f40262e959d9d43178dda600432da56b/src/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py#L1657) with the default number of threads. Hence, sending `50` requests simultaneously, as in your case, would lead to threadpool starvation, meaning that there wouldn't be enough threads available in the threadpool to handle **all** incoming requests concurrently.

As described earlier, one can adjust that value, thus **increasing the number of threads**, which might lead to an improvement in performance results—always **depending** on the number of requests to `def` endpoints (or `async def` endpoints that create calls to `run_in_threadpool()` inside) your API is expected to serve concurrently. For instance, if you expect the API to serve no more than 50 requests at a time to such endpoints, then set the maximum number of threads to 50. **Note:** If your FastAPI application also uses *synchronous*/*blocking* [background tasks](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/) and/or [`StreamingResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#streamingresponse)'s generators (i.e., functions defined with normal `def` instead of `async def`) and/or [`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile)'s `async` methods, such as `read`/`write`/etc. (all these methods call the corresponding *synchronous* `def` file methods underneath, using `run_in_threadpool()`), you could then **increase the number of threads as required**, as FastAPI actually runs all those functions in the same external threadpool as well—it is all explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) in details.

Note that using the approach below, which was described [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/4221#issuecomment-982260467), would have the same effect on adjusting the number of worker threads:

```py
from anyio.lowlevel import RunVar
from anyio import CapacityLimiter

RunVar("_default_thread_limiter").set(CapacityLimiter(60))
```

But, it would be best to follow the approach provided by AnyIO's official documentation (as shown earlier). It is also a good idea to have this done when the application starts up, using a `lifespan` event handler, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804).

In the working example below, since the `/sync` endpoint is defined with normal `def` instead of `async def`, FastAPI will run it in a separate thread from the external threadpool and `await` it, thus ensuring the event loop (and hence, the main thread and the entire server) does not get blocked due to the blocking operations (either blocking IO-bound or CPU-bound) that will be performed inside that endpoint.

##### Working Example 1

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from anyio import to_thread
import time


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):    
    to_thread.current_default_thread_limiter().total_tokens = 60
    yield


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.get("/sync")
def test_sync() -> None:
    time.sleep(3)
    print("sync")


@app.get('/get_available_threads')
async def get_available_threads():
    return to_thread.current_default_thread_limiter().available_tokens
```

Using ApacheBench, you could test the example above as follows, which will send `1000` requests in total with `50` being sent simultaneously at a time (`-n`: Number of requests, `-c` : Number of concurrent requests):

```
ab -n 1000 -c 50 "http://localhost:8000/sync"
```

While running a performance test on the example above, if you call the `/get_available_threads` endpoint from your browser, e.g., `http://localhost:8000/get_available_threads`, you would see that the amount of threads **available** is always 10 or above (since only 50 threads are used at a time in this test, but the thread limiter was set to `60`), meaning that setting the maximum number of threads on AnyIO's thread limiter to a number that is well above your needs, like `200` as shown in some other answer and in your recent example, wouldn't bring about any improvements in the performance; on the contrary, you would end up with a number of threads "sitting" there without being used. As explained earlier, the number of maximum threads should depend on (1) the number of requests your API is expected to serve concurrently, (2) any additional blocking tasks/functions that would run in the threadpool by FastAPI itself under the hood, as well as (3) the server machine's resources available.

The example below is the **same** as the one above, but instead of letting FastAPI itself to handle the blocking operation(s) inside the `def` endpoint (by running the `def` endpoint in the external threadpool and `await`ing it), the endpoint is now defined with `async def` (meaning that FastAPI will run it directly in the event loop), and inside the endpoint, `run_in_threadpool()` (which returns an `await`able) is used  to run the blocking operation (i.e., `time.sleep()` in the example). Performing a benchmark test on the example below would yield similar results to the previous example.

##### Working Example 2

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.concurrency import run_in_threadpool
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from anyio import to_thread
import time


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):    
    to_thread.current_default_thread_limiter().total_tokens = 60
    yield


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.get("/sync_async_run_in_tp")
async def test_sync_async_with_run_in_threadpool() -> None:
    await run_in_threadpool(time.sleep, 3)
    print("sync_async using FastAPI's run_in_threadpool")


@app.get('/get_available_threads')
async def get_available_threads():
    return to_thread.current_default_thread_limiter().available_tokens
```

Using ApacheBench, you could test the example above as follows:

```
ab -n 1000 -c 50 "http://localhost:8000/sync_async_run_in_tp"
```

### Using [`loop.run_in_executor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) with [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor)

When using `asyncio`'s [`loop.run_in_executor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)—after obtaining the running event loop using [`asyncio.get_running_loop()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_running_loop)—one could pass `None` to the `executor` argument, which would lead to the *default* executor being used; that is, a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor). **Note** that when calling `loop.run_in_executor()` and passing `None` to the `executor` argument, this **does not** create a new instance of a `ThreadPoolExecutor` every time you do that; instead, a `ThreadPoolExecutor` is only initialised once the first time you do that, but for subsequent calls to `loop.run_in_executor()` with passing `None` to the `executor` argument, Python **reuses** that very same instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor` (hence, the *default* executor). This can been seen in the [source code of `loop.run_in_executor()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/39ec7fbba84663ab760853da2ac422c2e988d189/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L872). That means, the number of threads that can be created, when calling `await loop.run_in_executor(None, ...)`, is **limited** to the default number of thread workers in the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class.

As described in the documentation of `ThreadPoolExecutor`—and as shown in its implementation [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d466052ad48091a00a50c5298f33238aff591028/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py#L145)—by default, the `max_workers` argument is set to `None`, in which case, the number of worker threads is set based on the following equation: `min(32, os.cpu_count() + 4)`. The [`os.cpu_count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.cpu_count) function reutrns the number of *logical* CPUs in the current system. As explained in [this article](https://superfastpython.com/number-of-cpus-python/), *physical* cores refers to the number of CPU cores provided in the hardware (e.g., the chips), while *logical* cores is the number of CPU cores **after** hyperthreading is taken into account. If, for instance, your machine has 4 physical cores, each with hyperthreading (most modern CPUs have this), then Python will see 8 CPUs and will allocate 12 threads (8 CPUs + 4) to the pool by default (Python limits the number of threads to 32 to "avoid consuming surprisingly large resources on multi-core machines"; however, one could always adjust the `max_workers` argument on their own when using a custom `ThreadPoolExecutor`, instead of using the *default* one). You could check the default number of worker threads on your system as follows:

```py
import concurrent.futures

# create a thread pool with the default number of worker threads
pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()

# report the number of worker threads chosen by default
# Note: `_max_workers` is a protected variable and may change in the future
print(pool._max_workers)
```

Now, as shown in your original example, you are not using a custom `ThreadPoolExecutor`, but instead using the *default* `ThreadPoolExecutor` every time a request arrives, by calling `await loop.run_in_executor(None, time.sleep, 3)` (inside the `sync_async_func()` function, which is triggered by the `/test/sync_async` endpoint). Assuming your machine has 4 physical cores with hyperthreading enabled (as explained in the example earlier), then the default number of worker threads for the *default* `ThreadPoolExecutor` would be 12. That means, based on your original example and the `/test/sync_async` endpoint that triggers the `await loop.run_in_executor(None, time.sleep, 3)` function, your application could only handle 12 concurrent requests at a time. That is the **main reason** for the difference observed in the performance results when compared to using `run_in_threadpool()`, which comes with `40` allocated threads by default. Even though, in both cases, a threadpool starvation was caused when sending `50` requests simultaneously, the endpoint (in your example) that uses `run_in_threadpool()` performed better only because the default number of threads created was greater than the one used by the *default* `ThreadPoolExecutor` (in your other endpoint).

One way to solve this is to create a new instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor` (on your own, instead of using the *default* executor) every time a request arrives and have it terminated once the task is completed (using the `with` statement), as shown below:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as pool:
    await loop.run_in_executor(pool, time.sleep, 3)
```

Although the above should wok just fine, it would be best to **instantiate a `ThreadPoolExecutor` once** at application startup, **adjust the number of worker threads** as needed, and **reuse the executor** when required. Having said that, depending on the blocking task and/or external libraries you might be using for that task, if you ever encounter a memory leak—i.e., memory that is no longer needed, but is not released—after tasks are completed when reusing a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, you might find creating a new instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor` each time, as shown above, more suitable. **Note**, however, that if this was a [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) instead, creating and destroying many processes over and over could become **computationally expensive**. Creating and destroying too many threads could consume huge memory as well.

Below is a complete working example, demonstrating how to create a reusable custom `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Calling  the `/get_active_threads` endpoint from your browser, e.g., `http://localhost:8000/get_active_threads`, while running a performance test with ApacheBench (using `50` concurrent requests, as described in your question and as shown below), you would see that the number of **active** threads never goes above `51` (50 concurrent threads + 1, which is the main thread), despite setting the `max_workers` argument to `60` in the example below. This is simply because, in this performance test, the application is never required to serve more than `50` requests at the same time. Also, `ThreadPoolExecutor` won't spawn new threads, if idle threads are available (thus, saving resources)—see the [relevant implementation part](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9afc6d102d16080535325f645849cd84eb04d57d/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py#L181). Hence, again, initialising the `ThreadPoolExecutor` with `max_workers=100`, as shown in your recent update, would be unecessary, if you never expect your FastAPI application to serve more than 50 requests at a time (to endpoints where that `ThreadPoolExecutor` is used).

##### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
import concurrent.futures
import threading
import asyncio
import time


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):    
    pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=60)
    yield {'pool': pool}
    pool.shutdown()


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.get("/sync_async")
async def test_sync_async(request: Request) -> None:
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(request.state.pool, time.sleep, 3)  
    print("sync_async")


@app.get('/get_active_threads')
async def get_active_threads():
    return threading.active_count()
```

Using ApacheBench, you could test the example above as follows:

```
ab -n 1000 -c 50 "http://localhost:8000/sync_async"
```

### Final Notes

In general, you should always aim to use *asynchronous* code (i.e., using `async`/`await`), wherever is possible, as `async` code, also known as coroutines, runs *directly* in the event loop—the event loop runs in the main thread and executes all tasks in that thread. That means there is only **one** thread that can take a lock on the interpreter; thus, avoiding the additional overhead of *context switching* (i.e., the CPU jumping from one thread of execution to another). When dealing with *sync* blocking IO-bound tasks though, you could either (1) define your endpoint with `def` and let FastAPI handle it behind the scenes as described earlier, as well as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804), or (2) define your endpoint with `async def` and use `run_in_threadpool()` on your own to run that blocking task in a separate thread and `await` it, or (3) define your endpoint with `async def` and use `asyncio`'s `loop.run_in_executor()` with a custom (preferably reusable) `ThreadPoolExecutor`, adjusting the number of worker threads as required. When required to perform blocking CPU-bound tasks, while running such tasks in a separate from an external threadpool and `await`ing them would successfully prevent the event loop from getting blocked, it wouldn't, however, provide the performance improvement you would expect from running code in parallel. Thus, for CPU-bound tasks, one may choose to use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` instead (**Note:** when using processes in general, you need to explicitly protect the entry point with `if __name__ == '__main__'`)—example on using a `ProcessPoolExecutor` can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77862153/17865804).

To run tasks in the background, without waiting for them to complete in order to proceed with executing the rest of the code in an endpoint, you could use FastAPI's [`BackgroundTasks`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76280152) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73283272). If the background task function is defined with `async def`, FastAPI will run it directly in the event loop, whereas if it is defined with normal `def`, FastAPI will use `run_in_threadpool()` and `await` the returned coroutine (same concept as API endpoints). Another option when you need to run an `async def` function in the background, but not necessarily having it trigerred after returning a FastAPI response (which is the case in `BackgroundTasks`), is to use [`asyncio.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task), as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70873984/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148361/17865804). If you need to [perform heavy background computation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74508996/17865804) and you don't necessarily need it to be run by the same process, you may benefit from using other bigger tools such as Celery.

Finally, regarding the **optimal/maximum number of worker threads**, I would suggest reading [this article](https://superfastpython.com/threadpoolexecutor-number-of-threads/) (have a look at [this article](https://superfastpython.com/threadpoolexecutor-in-python/) as well for more details on `ThreadPoolExecutor` in general). As explained in the article:

> It is important to **limit the number** of worker threads in the thread
> pools to the number of asynchronous tasks you wish to complete, **based
> on** the resources in your system, or on the number of resources you
> intend to use within your tasks.
>
> Alternately, you may wish to **increase the number** of worker threads
> dramatically, **given the greater capacity** in the resources you intend
> to use.
>
> [...]
>
> It is common to have **more threads than CPUs** (physical or logical) in
> your system. The reason for this is that threads are used for IO-bound tasks, not
> CPU-bound tasks. This means that threads are used for tasks that wait
> for relatively slow resources to respond, like hard drives, DVD
> drives, printers, network connections, and much more.
>
> Therefore, **it is not uncommon** to have tens, hundreds and even
> thousands of threads in your application, **depending on your specific
> needs**. It is unusual to have more than one or a few thousand threads.
> If you require this many threads, then alternative solutions may be
> preferred, such as `AsyncIO`.

Also, in the same article:

> ##### Does the Number of Threads in the `ThreadPoolExecutor` Match the Number of CPUs or Cores?
>
> The number of worker threads in the `ThreadPoolExecutor` is **not
> related** to the number of CPUs or CPU cores in your system.
>
> You can configure the number of threads **based on** the number of
> tasks you need to execute, the amount of local system resources you
> have available (e.g., memory), and the limitations of resources you
> intend to access within your tasks (e.g., connections to remote
> servers).
>
> ##### How Many Threads Should I Use?
>
> If you have hundreds of tasks, you should probably set the number of
> threads to be equal to the number of tasks.
>
> If you have thousands of tasks, you should probably cap the number of
> threads at hundreds or 1,000.
>
> If your application is intended to be executed multiple times in the
> future, you can test different numbers of threads and compare overall
> execution time, then choose a number of threads that gives
> approximately the best performance. You may want to mock the task in
> these tests with a random sleep operation.
>
> ##### What Is the Maximum Number of Worker Threads in the `ThreadPoolExecutor`?
>
> There is no maximum number of worker threads in the
> `ThreadPoolExecutor`.
>
> Nevertheless, your system will have an upper limit of the number of
> threads you can create based on **how much main memory (RAM) you have
> available**.
>
> Before you exceed main memory, you will reach a point of diminishing
> returns in terms of adding new threads and executing more tasks. This
> is because your operating system must switch between the threads,
> called *context switching*. With too many threads active at once, your
> program may spend more time context switching than actually executing
> tasks.
>
> A sensible upper limit for many applications is hundreds of threads to
> perhaps a few thousand threads. More than a few thousand threads on a
> modern system may result in too much context switching, depending on
> your system and on the types of tasks that are being executed.

Comment: Wow, that's a great response, very comprehensive and informative. It gives me all the clues to solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: This morning, I conducted some tests regarding background tasks and observed the results I obtained. I performed two simple tests: one involving a synchronous route with an asynchronous background task, and the other involving a synchronous route with a synchronous background task. The first result for 500 requests averaged 3.3 seconds, while the result for the synchronous route with the synchronous task averaged 5.8 seconds. Does that seem coherent to you? A synchronous task means that the function invoked by the task is either synchronous using time.sleep or asynchronous using asyncio.sleep.

Comment: Despite the last statement in your comment, it does. This is because a background task has nothing to do with the endpoint itself. Please have a look at a recent [comment on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76279889/how-to-use-background-tasks-inside-a-function-that-is-called-by-a-fastapi-endpoi/76280152#comment137407145_76280152).

Comment: There is probably an element that I didn't understand in the comment you linked me. I understood that the background task has nothing to do with the endpoint, and that in this case, FastAPI will handle both the background task and the endpoint in the same way regarding async def and def. Therefore, I should have the same result.

Comment: The `async def` background task, in your former test, will run directly in the event loop, while the `def` background task, in your latter test, will run in a separate thread from the external threadpool (which will then be `await`ed).

Answer (score 2):

`starlette.concurrency.run_in_threadpool` uses [`anyio.to_thread.run_sync()`](https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#anyio.to_thread.run_sync) under the hood.

By default, the concurrency there [is limited to 40](https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/threads.html#adjusting-the-default-maximum-worker-thread-count), so 50 concurrent requests will starve the threadpool; you can increase that limit with

```
from anyio import to_thread

to_thread.current_default_thread_limiter().total_tokens = 200
```

Similarly, [`run_in_executor` uses a default `ThreadPoolExecutor` if you don't pass in one](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor); the default worker count for the default executor is [`min(32, os.cpu_count() + 4)`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor), so depending on your configuration, that too may be way too little.

Comment: Great! Indeed, that's it. Thank you very much. However, I have   (two)questions about the basic setup for FastAPI, and how it handles asynchronous requests by default. Also, in the context of an application (running on cloud run) where I'll be using run_executor or run_in_threadpool specifically for API calls (like Google) that don't inherently support async, how do I evaluate the maximum number of workers for ThreadpoolExecutor and the maximum concurrency for run_in_threadpool?

Comment: There's no simple answer to "maximum number of workers" – if you have 4 cores, each workers gets allocated to a core and all of your workers happen to be using 100% of that core all the time, your machine is already starved. However, that's not generally the case.

Comment: One thing seems surprising to me. Why do I not get the same result between the /async route and run_in_threadpool without changing the thread limiter? FastAPI uses Starlette; shouldn't we expect the same result?

Answer (score 0):

1. Set `--limit-concurrency 100` for `uvicorn`
2. Change default `default_thread_limiter.total_tokens`. The default limit is 40.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from anyio.to_thread import get_asynclib

app = FastAPI()
@app.on_event("startup")
def startup():
    print("starting app ... ")
    get_asynclib().current_default_thread_limiter().total_tokens = 100
    print('default _default_thread_limiter', get_asynclib().current_default_thread_limiter().total_tokens)
```

3. Run sync task use `run_in_threadpool`.

```
from starlette.concurrency import run_in_threadpool

@app.post("/blocking")
async def create_flow():
    await run_in_threadpool(sub_task, t=100)

def sub_task(t=1):
    import subprocess
    cmd = f'echo sleeping...; sleep {t}'
    stdout, stderr = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True).communicate()
```

> or use: `run_in_threadpool(func, *args, limiter=get_asynclib().CapacityLimiter(10))`

4. export log when set `--limit-concurrency` is `5` and `default_thread_limiter.total_tokens` is 3.

```
# start the web app
starting app ... 
default _default_thread_limiter 3
# start call use `cURL`.
call sync ..
sleeping ...
call sync ..
sleeping ...
call sync ..
sleeping ...
# The first three execute normally, the rest are suspended
call sync ..
call sync ..
# Exceed concurrency limit(5) for `uvicorn`.
Exceeded concurrency limit.
Exceeded concurrency limit.
...
```

> Note: Chrome or other broswer limit connections is `6` for per hostname, May affect testing.