# Is uvicorn used for an external threadpool or an internal event loop which runs in the main (single) thread

Tags: python, multithreading, fastapi

FastAPI uses `uvicorn` package to run the script:

```
main:app --reload
```

The docs explain that:

> Uvicorn is an ASGI web server implementation for Python... The ASGI specification fills this gap, and means we're now able to start building a common set of tooling usable across all async frameworks.
>
> ...will install uvicorn with "Cython-based" dependencies (where possible) and other "optional extras".In this context, "Cython-based" means the following:
>
> - the event loop uvloop will be installed and used if possible.
>   **uvloop is a fast, drop-in replacement of the built-in asyncio event loop**. It is implemented in Cython. The built-in asyncio event loop serves as an easy-to-read reference implementation and is there for easy debugging as it's pure-python based.

Also, [this great](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/2545680) answer explains that:

> Thus, `def` endpoints (in the context of asynchronous programming, a function defined with just `def` is called synchronous function), in FastAPI, **run in a separate thread from an external threadpool** that is then awaited, and hence, FastAPI will still work asynchronously. In other words, the server will process requests to such endpoints concurrently. Whereas, `async def` endpoints run directly in the event loop which runs in the main (single) thread...

So my question what is `uvicorn` in this context - a separate thread from an external threadpool or an event loop which runs in the main (single) thread? From the description above it seems `uvicorn` replaces the built-in event loop where `def` functions are executed. Correct? If so, what is used for a separate thread from an external threadpool?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Please take a look at [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77941425/17865804) as well.

Comment: Uvicorn is an ASGI server that is used to [run a FastAPI application](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/manually). When calling Uvicorn's [`run()`](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/a05ae6426cc8f224f4f1a995f46a901ab0f5644b/uvicorn/server.py#L60) method, an event loop is created and used to serve the application ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148361/17865804) might prove helpful as well).

Comment: Endpoints/functions defined with normal `def` will not run *directly* in the event loop (as they would block the event loop/main thread), but will rather run in a separate thread from an external threadpool, using `anyio.to_thread.run_sync()`, which will return a coroutine that can be `await`ed, and hence, FastAPI will still work *asynchronously*. Please refer to the linked answers above for more details.