# How to use Lifespan events in synchronous fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi, httpx

I want to use httpx for better performance in my Fastapi web server.
I want to initiate it using the lifespan event as written in the [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/?h=asynccontextmanager#lifespan) or in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76322463/how-to-initialise-a-global-object-or-variable-and-reuse-it-in-every-fastapi-endp/76322910#76322910).

I'm using Fastapi as a synchronous server without the async functionality.

Does it matter? The `asynccontextmanager` fits both or only if I use Fastapi with async?

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77941425/17865804) for more details on how FastAPI works under the hood.

Comment: It should also be noted that `httpx` offers a standard synchronous API as well, and one  could [spawn a `Client`](https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/clients/#usage) and reuse it inside `def` endpoints in a similar way as an `AsyncClient`, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804). Regardless, I would still suggest having a look at all the links provided above, in order to better understand how FastAPI works under the hood, as well as when you should define an endpoint with normal `def` or `async def`.